# How to consume but ignore a character in RegEx

Tags: regex

Is there any RegEx expression - without using replace - to match against:

```
AB.D..G
ABCDEFG
```

and return in each case as a match

```
ABDG
ABCDEFG
```

Comment: Without using replace, desired output can be obtained with ''.join(re.findall('[A-Z]+', strtxt))

Comment: Thank you, the key here is “without using...” For anyone searching this you cannot disregard matched characters so it has to be post-processes.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to use this pattern: `\w{1,}`

```js
var str1 = 'AB.D..G';
var str2 = 'ABCDEFG';
var pattern = /\w{1,}/g;

console.log(str1.match(pattern).join(''));
console.log(str2.match(pattern).join(''));
```

`\w` means: any alphabet character

`{1,}` means: one or more times

`g` means: repeat this method multiple times

And we use `join` method to join all of the matched characters to a string.

Answer (score 0):

You can split and join the string.